# Data not loading to input field in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I have an input field in a component html file in Angular 8

```
<!-- simplified -->    
<form>
<div *ngFor="let r of reviews">
<input name="Text" value="{{ r.reviewText }}" [(ngModel)]="r.reviewText" />
</div>
</form>
```

The [(ngModel)] updates (http puts) the data back to the db nicely.
The problem is that `value="{{ r.reviewText }}"` does not load the data as it exists in the database back to that field when the page is loaded or reloaded. I can type stuff in, but the input field is always blank on load/reload. That is the case whether the syntax is `value="{{ r.reviewText }}"` or `[value]="r.reviewText"`.

If I remove `[(ngModel)]="r.reviewText"` -- then the data is loaded into the value for that field, but then obviously the binding in terms of updating back to the db doesn't work. Its as if the ngModel and value elements are mutually exclusive. I understand [(ngModel)] to be double binding - but in this case it seems to be only single binding - pushing back to the db ok, but not going the other way. I tried something similar with textarea, but it has the same problem as input - it doesn't display r.reviewText, but the ngModel works:

```
<textarea name="Text" [(ngModel)]="r.reviewText" >{{ r.reviewText }}</textarea>
```

Note: If I put `{{ r.reviewText }}` elsewhere on the page, not in the input or textarea tag, the data from the db is displayed in that position on load/reload - and then also mirroring what I type into the input field as I type - as expected.

How can I display the db contents for `{{ r.reviewText }}` in the value parameter of the input on page load or refresh, while still being able to update/save updated content to the db with [(ngModel)] ? Any comment appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi can you print the whole reviews array here please.

Comment: it looks issue is with *ngFor.. use **asyn** and have a try `*ngFor="let r of reviews | async"`

Comment: review object is like : `{
    "id": 1399,
    "reviewText": "ghjjhhh",
    "okNotOk": false,
    "toBeDeleted": false,
    "reviewerName": "reviewer1",
    "itemCode": "YFS001"
}`

Comment: *ngFor="let r of reviews", here reviews is array or object? First clarify this!

Comment: Sunny - its an array of 2000 objects , I just gave you one example case -not going to put in the whole array

Comment: @AkhilNaidu -- I have tried adding an async pipe to the ngFor, and I am getting `ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'` type errors. I think my component.ts would need adjusting before I can use async -- I might play around with this more. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the html `<form>` tag enabled the `{{ r.reviewText }}` to display as a value for the input tag, or within the textarea tag, on page reload. ngModel 2-way binding works.

I don't know why yet, or whether deleting the form tag will have side-effects down the track..

These suggest pointers - but nothing as to why deleting the html `<form>` tag entirely, seems to work.
[Angular error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48601194/angular-error-if-ngmodel-is-used-within-a-form-tag-either-the-name-attribute-m) --and --
[Angular 2 - ngModel does not work inside <form> after updating to rc4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942411/angular-2-ngmodel-does-not-work-inside-form-after-updating-to-rc4)

To all those who might want to suggest I include the formsModule in app.module.ts -- that has always been there and remains; that's not the problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need value 
[(ngModel)] is used for 2 way binding and it should work as expected without value

```
<input name="Text" [(ngModel)]="r.reviewText" />
```

A very small example on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keprkp

Comment: Merely deleting the value parameter does not work. Your stackblitz example does not have a database connected to load data to the value parameter of the input field -- it does not demonstrate loading data back to the field on page load/reload: Which is the problem I am describing. ie: My case behaves like your stackblitz example, except I have a database -- and want to see the already existing data for that parameter displaying, on page reload

Comment: I agree, if you combine Akhil's comment and this then it might work